# @font-face not working on SVG file, works on other text on the website

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-face

I have a website with an .SVG logo with a font that wont load.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('img/background.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif, 'walkway_boldregular';
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'walkway_boldregular';
    src: url('walkway_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('walkway_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('walkway_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('walkway_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/walkway_bold-webfont.svg#walkway_boldregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

I've read [here](http://www.fluorcow.com/embedding-fonts-on-a-website) that you have to have the correct ID after the .svg#, but when i open up the SVG in notepad there isn't any line with `<font id="">` so there's no id to add to the CSS.

If i order body like this

```
    body {
    background-image: url('img/background.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: 'walkway_boldregular', 'Open Sans', sans-serif,;
}
```

All the text on the website will be walkway_boldregular but not the SVG.

XML for the .svg looks like this

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
              <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

              <svg
                 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                 xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 version="1.1"
                 width="728"
                 height="90"
                 id="svg2985">
                <defs
                   id="defs2987">
                  <linearGradient
                     id="linearGradient5424">
                    <stop
                       id="stop5426"
                       style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
                       offset="0" />
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient
                     id="linearGradient3920">
                    <stop
                       id="stop3922"
                       style="stop-color:#33ccff;stop-opacity:1"
                       offset="0" />
                    <stop
                       id="stop3924"
                       style="stop-color:#33ccff;stop-opacity:0"
                       offset="1" />
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient
                     x1="-35.826744"
                     y1="61.715729"
                     x2="1167.1976"
                     y2="65.486961"
                     id="linearGradient3926"
                     xlink:href="#linearGradient3920"
                     gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
                  <linearGradient
                     x1="18.776352"
                     y1="40.02018"
                     x2="739.62109"
                     y2="40.02018"
                     id="linearGradient5428"
                     xlink:href="#linearGradient5424"
                     gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
                </defs>
                <metadata
                   id="metadata2990">
                  <rdf:RDF>
                    <cc:Work
                       rdf:about="">
                      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                      <dc:type
                         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                      <dc:title></dc:title>
                    </cc:Work>
                  </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g
                   id="layer3">
                  <rect
                     width="752.66669"
                     height="122"
                     x="-9.333333"
                     y="-13.333333"
                     id="rect3893"
                     style="fill:url(#linearGradient3926);fill-opacity:1" />
                </g>
                <g
                   id="layer4" />
                <g
                   id="layer2">
                  <text
                     x="15.796598"
                     y="63.827888"
                     transform="scale(0.87047566,1.1487972)"
                     id="text3851"
                     xml:space="preserve"
                     style="font-size:44.34981918px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:url(#linearGradient5428);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;font-family:Walkway Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:Walkway Bold"><tspan
                       x="15.796598"
                       y="63.827888"
                       id="tspan3853"
                       style="font-size:70.95970917px;font-weight:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;fill:url(#linearGradient5428);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;-inkscape-font-specification:'Walkway Bold,'">HOTELL TJUVHOLMEN</tspan></text>
                  <image
                     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAI4CAYAAAC2kpeGAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAHBpJREFU eJzt3dGO40hyBVDVYv//l8sP657prpbElBRkxCXPAQwbsL0geTMj70gqztf39/cNYLBHQ+rr0KsA eMF/ui8A4Iln/wTonw6BsRQsYKqVAqVkASMpWMBErxQnJQsYR8ECpnmnMClZwCgKFjDJJ0VJyQLG ULCAKSoK0nfRfw7ARxQsoNsepUjJAlopWECnPYuQkgW0UbCALkcUICULaKFgAR2OLD5KFnA4BQs4 WkfhUbKAQylYwJE6i46SBRxGwQKOMqHgTLgG4AIULOAIk4qNd2UBu1OwgD1NLjNTrws4AQUL2EtC gUm4RiCQggXsIam4JF0rEELBAqolFpbEawYGU7CASslFJfnagWEULKDKGQrKGe4BGEDBAiqcqZic 6V6AJv/tvgAg2lnLyK/7+mq9CiCWT7CAd521XP3uCvcI7EDBAt5xpeJxpXsFiihYwKuuWDiueM/A BxQs4BVXLhpXvnfgRQoWsErB8AyARQoWsEKx+JdnAWxSsIAtCsXfPBPgKe/BAh5RIp7zrizgIZ9g AfcoV+s8K+AvChbwk8LwOs8M+IOCBfxOUXifZwf8Q8ECflEQPucZArfbTcEC/kcxqONZAgoWoBDs wDOFi1Ow4NoUgf183zxfuCzvwTqGIfs67xbalzV5nO+b9QyX4xMsuB7l6nieOVyMggXX4qDv49nD hShYcB0O+H4ygItQsOAaHOxzyAIuQMGC83OgzyMTODkFC87NQT6XbODEFCw4Lwf4fN6VBSelYDGR dwZ9xqGdR15wMgoWnIuDOpfs4EQULDgPB3Q+GcJJKFhwDg7m85AlnICCBfkcyOcjUwinYEE2B/F5 yRaCKViQywF8fjKGUP/tvgDgZQ7da/mVt9eXQBCfYEEW5eq6ZA9BFCzI4YDFGoAQChZkcLDyi7UA ARQsmM+Byk/WBAynYMFsDlIesTZgMAUL5nKAssUagaEULJjJwckqawUG8h4smMVhyTu8KwuG8QkW zKFc8SlrCIZQsGAGByNVrCUYQMGCfg7ENV+//RfPWVPQTMGCXg7CbfdKlZK1zdqCRgoW9HEAbntW pJSsbdYYNFGwoIeDb9tKgVKytllr0EDBguM58La9UpyUrG3WHBxMwYLjfN8cdCveKUxK1jbrDw6k YMExHGxrPilKStYaaxEOoGDB/hxoayoKkpK1xpqEnSlYsC8H2ZrKYuRdWWusTdiRggX7cYBt27MM KVnbrFHYiYIF+3BwbTuiAClZ26xV2IGCBfUcWNuOLD5K1jZrFoopWFDLQbWto/AoWdu8xgEKKVhQ w+G0prPoKFlrrGMooGDB5xxIayYUnAnXkMCahg8pWPAZB9GaScVm0rVMZm3DBxQseJ8DaM3EQuNd WWuscXiTggXvcfBsSygx069vAmsd3qBgwescONuSikvStXax5uFFCha8xkGzLbGwJF7z0ax9eIGC xTSTDzoHzLbJ+W1JvvajeB0JLFKwmGTqAedQWTM1v1ec4R6OYD/ABgWLKaYebA6SNVPze8eZ7mVP 9gY8oWDRbfJfmjlA1kzN7xOT1+Uk9gg8oGDRafIB5uDYdoUScvb7q2CvwB0KFl0mH1wOjG2T86t2 pXt9lz0DPyhYdJh8YDkotk3Oby9XvOdX2TvwGwWLo00+qBwQ2ybnt7cr3/sqewj+n4LFkaYeUF7D sGZqfkfyDLbZT3BTsDjO1IPJQbBman4dPIs19haXpmBxhKkHkgNgzdT8Onkma+wxLkvBYm9TDyKD f83U/Ca4wmsqKthrXJKCxV4mHz4G/rbJ+U3jOW2z57gcBYs9TD5wDPptk/ObyjPbZu9xKQoW1SYf NAb8tsn5TefZbbMHuQwFi0qTDxiDfdvk/FJ4htvsRS5BwaLK1IPFO3nWTM0vkWe5zb7k9BQsKkw9 UAzwNVPzS+aZrrFHOS0Fi09NPUgM7jVT87sn7VOPpGfbKSlTWKZg8YmpB4iBvWZqfvd8//ifUzL2 uos1KXnCMgWLd009NAzqbUmH/rMylZR1yvPulJQnbFKweMfUw8KA3jY1u3tW8kzKPOnZd0nKE55S sHjF5E8+DOZtU7O755U8k7JPyqBLUp7wkILFqskHg4G8bXJ+P72TZ9IaSMqiS1KecJeCxYqpB0LS j507Tc3vnk/yTFoLSZl0sb+JpmCxZepBYPCumZrfPRWZJq2LpGw6JWUK/1CweGbqAWDgrpma3z2V mSatj6SMOiVlCrfbTcHisamD36BdMzW/e/bINOnrpcl/PDJJSp5wu90ULO6bOuwN2G1Jh/URJShp zaTk1ikpTy5OweKnqUPeYN02Nbt7jswzae0kZdglKU8uTMHid1OHu4G6bWp293TkmbSGkrLskpQn F6VgcbvN/lrJIN02Nbt7OvNMWktJmXZJ+p0dF6RgMXWQG55rpuZ3z4Q8J1zDqqRsOyVlyoUoWNc2 dYAbmGum5nfPpEwnXcuWpIw7JWXKRShY1zV1cBuUa6bmd8/ETJM+IU3KulNKnlyEgnVNUwe2Ablt 8u/lfkooMdOv75ek3Dul5MkFKFjXM3VIG4zbpmZ3T1KeSdeatAa6JOXJiSlY1zJ1OBuI26Zmd09i nknXnLQWuiTlyUkpWNcxdSgbhNumZndPcp5J1560Jrok5ckJKVjXMHEYJ/w+Z4KJ2T1yhjyT7iFp bXQxZ2ijYJ3fxCFs4K2ZmN0jZ8o06V6S1kinpEw5CQXrvKb+1ZFBt2Zido+cMdOke0paK52SMuUE FKxzmjpwDbg1U/O758yZJn29NPUfqKZJyZMTULDOZ+qQNdi2JR2SSeXjU0n3mbJ+OiXlSTAF61ym DlcDbdvU7O65Yp5J95y0lrok5UkoBes8pg5Vg2zb1OzuuXKeSfeetKa6JOVJIAXrHKYOUwNs29Ts 7pFn1jNIWltdkvIkjIKVb+IQvdLvcz4xMbtH5PmvpGeRtMa6mFfsQsHKNnF4GlRrJmb3iEz/lvRM ktZap6RMCaBg5Zo4NA2oNROze0SmjyU9m6Q11ykpU4ZTsPJM/VN+g2nNxOwekem2pK+Xps6OaVLy ZDgFK8vU4WggbUs63JJKwxRJzytlHXZKypOhFKwcU4eiQbRtanb3yPN9Sc8uaU12ScqTgRSsDFOH oQG0bWp298jzc0nPMGltdknKk2EUrPmmDkGDZ9vU7O6RZ52kZ5m0Rrsk5ckgCtZsE4ef3+esmZjd I/Ksl/RMk9ZqF3OPlylYc00cegbMmonZPSLT/SQ926Q12ykpU5opWDNNHHYGy5qJ2T0i0/0lPeOk tdspKVMaKVjzTBxyBsqaidk9ItPjJH29lPQ6kU4pedJIwZpj6mAzSLZNze6epMP+bJKee8p67pSU Jw0UrBmmDjMDZNvU7O6RZ7+kDJLWdpekPDmYgtVv6hAzOLZNze4eec6RlEXSGu+SlCcHUrB6TR1e Bsa2qdndI895kjJJWutdfPXOXxSsPhOHliGxZmJ2j8hzrqRsktZ8p6RM2ZmC1WPisDIY1kzM7hGZ zpeUUdLa75SUKTtSsI43cUgZCGsmZveITHMkfXKctAc6peTJjhSsY00cTgbBmonZ3ZN0WPOnlNyS XkvSKSVPdvL1/W0NXJjwtyUdJPI8B2vuXJLypJBPsK7LYNyWNBjleR5JWSbtkS5JeVJIwbomG35b 0sEhz/NJyjRpr3RJypMiCta1+H3OmqQDQ57nlZRt0p7pYv5ejIJ1HTb2mqSDQqbnl5Rx0t7plJQp H1CwrsGGXpN0QMj0OpKyTtpDnZIy5U0K1vnZyGuSDgaZXk/S10tJe6lTSp68yWsazk2425IOA3ly u1mzZ5OUJy/wCdZ5GWzbkgabPPklaS0k7bEuSXnyAgXrnGzYbUmDX578lLQmkvZal6Q8WaRgnY+N ui1p4MuTR5LWRtKe65KUJwsUrPNI+hFsp6RBL0+2JK2RpL3XxRw/EQXrHGzINUkDXqasSlorSXuw U1KmPKBg5bMR1yQNdpnyqqQ1k7QXOyVlyh0KVjYbcE3SQJcp70r6eunrlrUvu6TkyR0KVi4bb1vS EE86HJktaR2l7M9OSXnyGwUrkw23LWlwy5NqSWsqaa92ScqT/6dg5bHRtiUNbHmyl6S1lbRnuyTl yU3BSmODbUsa1PJkb0lrLGnvdknK8/IUrAx+n7MmaUDLk6MkrbWkPdzFeRBCwZrPRlqTNJhlytGS 1lzSXu6UlOklKViz2UBrkgayTOmStPaS9nSnpEwvR8Gay8ZZkzSIZUq3pK+Xkl6z0iklz8tRsGay YbYlDd+kQ41rSFqPKfu8U1Kel6FgzWOjbEsauPJkqqS1mbTnuyTleQkK1iw2yLakQStPpktao0l7 v0tSnqenYM1hY2xLGrDyJEXSWk2aAV2S8jw1Bauf3+esSRqs8iRN0ppNmgVdnCsDKFi9bIA1SQNV pqRKWrtJM6FTUqano2D1sfDXJA1SmZIuaQ0nzYZOSZmeytf3t2ffwENfkzJA5ckZpey/280eXJGU 5yn4BOt4BsG2tHdcwRklre2UedEpKc9TULCOZYFvSxqU8uTsktZ40uzokpRnPAXrOBb2tqQBKU+u ImmtJ82QLkl5RlOwjmFBb0sajPLkapLWfNIs6eI1DgdQsPZlEa9JGojy5KqS1n7STOmUlGkcBWs/ Fu6apEEoU64uaQ8kzZZOSZlGUbD2YcGuSRqAMoX/SfpkPmnGdErJM4r3YNXzQLclDT15wmP28rkk 5TmeT7Bq2cDbkjawPOG5pD2SNHu6JOU5noJVx8LcljTg5AlrkvZK0gzqkpTnaApWDQtyW9Jgkye8 JmnPJM2iLkl5jqVgfSbpx56dkgaaPOE9SXsnaSZ1cb59SMF6n4W3JmmQyRQ+k7SHkmZTp6RMR1Gw 3mPBrUkaYDKFGkl7KWlGdUrKdAwF63UW2pqkwSVTqJX09VLSrOqUkucY3oP1Gg9rW9Kwkifsz0w4 l6Q8W/kEa52Nty1p48kTjpG015JmWJekPFspWGssqG1Jg0mecKykPZc0y7ok5dlGwdpmIW1LGkjy hB5Jey9ppnVJyrOFgvVY0o80OyUNInlCr6Q9mDTbujgnn1Cw7rNg1iQNIJnCDEl7MWnGdUrK9DAK 1t8slDVJg0emMEvSnkyadZ2SMj2EgvUnC2RN0sCRKcyU9PXS1y1r7nVJyfMQCta/LIxtSUMmaXjD lSXt05T51ykpz10pWP9jQWxLGizyhCxJezZpFnZJynM3CpaFsCJpoMgTMiXt3aSZ2CUpz11cvWBd fgEsSBok8oRsSXs4aTZ2Scqz3FULlt/nrEkaIPKEc0jay0kzsstlz9srFqxLBv2GpMEhUziXpD2d NCs7JWVa4moF63IBvylpYMgUzilpbyfNzE5JmX7sSgXrUsF+IGlQyBTOLenrpaTX2HRKyfNjVylY lwn0A0nDIWnoAp9L2u8pc7RTUp5vu0LBukSQH0oaCPKEa0ra+0kztUtSnm85e8E6fYAFkgaBPOHa kmZA0mztkpTny85csE4dXJGkASBP4HbLmgVJM7ZLUp4vOWPB8vucNUkbX57A75JmQtKs7XLKc/ts Bet0Ae0kacPLFLgnaTYkzdxOSZluOlPBOlUwO0ra6DIFnkn65CNp9nZKyXPTWQrWaQLZWcoGTxqa QL+UeZH0OpxOKXk+dYaCdYogdpa0qeUJvCNpdqTM405Jed6VXrDiAzhA0kaWJ/CJpBmSNJu7JOX5 l+SCFf3gD5K0geUJVEiaJUkzuktSnn9ILFh+n7MmaePKE6iUNFOSZnWXyHM/rWDFPeAmSRtWpsAe kmZL0szulJRpVMGKerCNkjaqTIE9Jc2YpNndKSbTlIIV80CbJW1QmQJHSPp6KWmGd4rI8+v7e/x1 jr/AAZI2pTyBLmbluYzOc/onWBbYttEL7Ad5Ap2SZlDSbO8yOs/JBWv0gxsiaQPKE5ggaRYlzfgu Y/OcWrDGPrBBkjaePIFJkmZS0qzvMjLPaQUr6ceInZI2nDyBiZJmU9LM7zKuP0wqWKMezGBJG02m wGRJMypp9ncak+mUgjXmgQyXtMFkCiRImlVJZ0CnEZlOKFgjHkSApI0lUyDJuK+Xnkg6Czq159n9 Hqz2BxAgaTPJE0hn5p5LW56dn2BZGNtsdIBjJc2ypDOiS1ueXQUraQF3Sdo48gTOJGmmJZ0VXVry 7ChYSQu3S9KGkSdwRkmzLenM6HJ4nkcWrKQfEXZK2ijyBM4sacYlnR1dDu0hRxWspEXaKWmDyBS4 gqRZl3SGdDok0yMKVtLi7JS0MWQKXEnSzEs6SzrtnuneBStpUXZK2hAyBa4o6WcuX7esc6XLrnnu WbBSFmKnpE2QNFwA9pI0B1POl0675blXwUpagF2SFr48Af6VNBOTzpouu+S5R8FKWnhdkha8PAH+ ljQbk86cLuV5VhespAXXJWmhyxPgsaQZmXT2dCnNs6pg+X3OmqQFLk+AbUmzMukM6lLWZyoKVtLi 6pS0sGUKsC5pZiadRZ0+zvTTgpW0qDolLWiZArwuaXYmnUmdPsr06/v77f//pMXUKWUhyxOgRsrc v93M/hVv5fnuJ1gC2Zb2jisAaiTN1JRzqtNbeb5TsJIWTpekBStPgHpJszXpzOrycp6vFqykBdMl aaHKE2A/STM26ezq8lKerxSspIXSJWmByhNgf0mzNukM67Kc50rB8o6rNUkLU54Ax0mauUlnWZel XrRVsJIWRaekBSlTgOMlzd6kM63T00yfFaykxdApaSHKFKBP0jdCSWdbp4d5PnoPVsoC6JS0+OQJ MIsz5Fz+yvPeJ1ge5DYbA4BPJM3mpDOvy195/ixYSYF3SVpo8gSYK2lGJ519Xf7I8z+P/hfclbTA 5AkwX9KsTjoDu/yT59f3B/8ywotJWlgyBcjijDmZd/9dhFdj4QOwp6TZnXQmtlGwtiUtpKQNCsCf kmZ40tnY4j83D+mZpGeTtDEBuM+7ss7h6/f3YKUEeoSkRSM3gHNyFmX6ut18RXiPBQ3ABEkzPuns PMTvBcvDyXoGSRsPgPckzfqkM3Qv/zyDn59gXfnhJN170oYD4DNJMz/pLK32x73f+4rwig8n6Z6T NhoANZJmf9KZWmXp30V49//wxJLuNWmDAVAr6QxIOls/dfden/3I/QoPJ+kekzYWAPtIOguSzth3 PbzHrb8iPPPDSbq3pA0FwL68K2uGp/f2tfivIkwJckVS2Gd67gDUc6b12Hzuq+/BSgrwmaT7ONNC BGAfSWdF0hn8sSu9aDQp2KQNA0CvpDMj6Sx+ZOkeXilYyQ8l6dqTNgoAMySdHUln8k/L1/7qJ1iJ DyXpmpM2CACzJJ0hSWfzLy9d8ztfESY9lKRrTdoYAMyUdJYkndEvX+u7v8FKeCgJ1/hL0oYAYLak MyXhrH7rGldf0/DI1BATArvd5j4/AM4h5Ty83WaeiW8/v0//inBacF+3edf0yMSFBMC5JJ01087v j66n4jUNUx7IlOtYkbTgAciWdOZMOcs/vo6zvAdrSiArkhY6AOeQdPYknekPVRWszoeRFETSAgfg XJLOoPheUfkJVsfDUK4AYF3SWRTdK6q/IjzyYShXAPC6pDMptlfs8RusIx5GUrkCAN4X2Sv2+pH7 ng9DuQKAa9nzNUy7/Ofu+VeE1Rec9I4rAKDeHt1iF3u/pqHqwhUrAOB2C+kWR7wH69MbUK4AgN+N 7xbTXzSqXAEA94zuCEcVrHcewugHBwC0G9svjvwE65UbUq4AgBUj+8XRXxGu3JhyBQC8Yly/6PgN 1qMb9BoGAOBdz3rE4f2i60fuP29UsQIAKozoGJ1/Rfj1478DAFRo7xjdr2lQrgCAPbR2jO6CBQBw OgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMEC ACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUU LACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQ TMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgA AMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiC BQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACK KVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsA oJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOw AACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAx BQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEA FFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoWAEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYgoW AEAxBQsAoJiCBQBQTMECACimYAEAFFOwAACKKVgAAMUULACAYv/tvgBgyVf3BTDKd/cFAM/5BAty OFQBQihYkMOnWAAhFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULIIff4UEIBQsAoJiCBZDDHzpACAULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAo pmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwA gGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzB AgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADF FCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUA UEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilY AADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCY ggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAA iilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQUL AKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRT sAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBAMQULAKCYggUAUEzBAgAopmABABRTsAAAiilYAADFFCwAgGIKFgBA MQULAKDY/wFUgApDq+C0CQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "
                     x="655.33331"
                     y="19.333344"
                     width="56.666668"
                     height="52"
                     id="image3977" />
                </g>
              </svg>
```

webfont svg file xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <metadata></metadata>
        <defs>
        <font id="walkway_boldregular" horiz-adv-x="1075" >
        <font-face units-per-em="2048" ascent="1638" descent="-410" />
        <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="724" />
        <glyph horiz-adv-x="2048" />
        <glyph horiz-adv-x="2048" />
        <glyph unicode="&#xd;" horiz-adv-x="724" />
        <glyph unicode=" "  horiz-adv-x="724" />
        <glyph unicode="&#x09;" horiz-adv-x="724" />
        <glyph unicode="&#xa0;" horiz-adv-x="724" />
        <glyph unicode="!" horiz-adv-x="397" d="M145 51v127q0 49 54 49q51 0 51 -49v-127q0 -51 -51 -51q-53 0 -54 51zM147 340v1049h105v-1049h-105z" />
        <glyph unicode="&#x22;" horiz-adv-x="598" d="M127 1165v168q0 43 51 43q53 0 53 -43v-168q0 -45 -53 -45q-51 0 -51 45zM362 1165v168q0 43 54 43q51 0 51 -43v-168q0 -45 -51 -45q-53 0 -54 45z" />
        <glyph unicode="#" horiz-adv-x="1087" d="M123 479l22 92h183l39 146h-187l29 92h180l39 149h107l-39 -149h182l37 149h106l-37 -149h183l-23 -92h-184l-37 -146h182l-22 -92h-183l-38 -149h-107l39 149h-182l-39 -149h-107l39 149h-182zM434 571h182l37 146h-180z" />
        <glyph unicode="$" horiz-adv-x="1314" d="M43 449v49h104v-43q0 -293 297 -369v621q-356 88 -356 344q0 291 356 360v131h105v-119q41 2 88 2q57 0 108 -4v121h105v-135q362 -82 367 -449h-103q-18 283 -264 349v-582q193 -47 274 -107q121 -88 121 -268q0 -152 -125 -254q-108 -87 -270 -116v-123h-105v108 q-35 -2 -69 -2q-66 0 -127 8v-114h-105v129q-401 94 -401 463zM193 1051q0 -172 251 -240v498q-252 -59 -251 -258zM549 68q59 -6 129 -7q35 0 67 2v582l-196 39v-616zM549 786l196 -36v573q-51 6 -108 6q-47 0 -88 -4v-539zM850 78q125 27 203 92q88 74 88 186 q0 105 -43 150q-61 63 -248 117v-545z" />
        <glyph unicode="%" horiz-adv-x="1536" d="M86 971q0 377 305 377t305 -377q0 -369 -307 -369q-303 0 -303 369zM193 971q0 -272 198 -273q199 0 199 273q0 280 -201 280q-197 0 -196 -280zM213 -2l1020 1391h125l-1018 -1391h-127zM842 330q0 379 307 379q303 0 303 -379q0 -369 -305 -369t-305 369zM948 330 q0 -272 201 -273q197 0 197 273q0 282 -199 282t-199 -282z" />
        <glyph unicode="&#x26;" horiz-adv-x="1234" d="M63 322q0 156 142 284q92 82 278 176q-236 125 -235 332q0 131 110 207q96 68 234 68q145 0 239 -66q106 -74 107 -213q0 -197 -391 -403q-195 -102 -260 -160q-119 -106 -119 -225t119 -193q109 -66 248 -66q266 0 391 222q70 125 69 288h105v-612h-105v242 q-174 -236 -448 -236q-182 0 -320 84q-164 98 -164 271zM352 1112q0 -176 234 -276q248 137 248 276q0 86 -76 137q-66 43 -162 43q-98 0 -168 -45q-76 -49 -76 -135z" />
        <glyph unicode="'" horiz-adv-x="358" d="M127 1165v168q0 43 51 43q53 0 53 -43v-168q0 -45 -53 -45q-51 0 -51 45z" />
        <glyph unicode="(" horiz-adv-x="477" d="M115 580q0 518 266 923h117q-279 -416 -279 -923q0 -508 279 -924h-117q-266 408 -266 924z" />
        <glyph unicode=")" horiz-adv-x="477" d="M-31 -344q287 416 287 924t-287 923h117q274 -399 274 -923q0 -523 -274 -924h-117z" />
        <glyph unicode="*" horiz-adv-x="696" d="M70 1235q0 12 13 28.5t38 16.5q10 0 20 -2h4l131 -61v112q0 47 54 47q51 0 51 -47v-112l127 57q14 6 27 6q27 0 45 -18q6 -14 6 -27q0 -29 -29 -41l-117 -51l117 -56q31 -14 31 -40q0 -45 -51 -46q-16 0 -31 7l-125 59v-113q0 -47 -51 -47q-53 0 -54 47v113l-124 -59 q-14 -6 -29 -7q-51 0 -51 46q0 27 30 40l117 56l-119 53q-31 12 -30 39z" />
```

Comment: you've got a slash before the font name for the SVG file, try taking that out

Comment: Removed the slash, but to my dismay it didn't work.

Comment: Is the XML that you pasted the full contents of the walkway_bold-webfont.svg file?

Comment: No it wasn't, i've added that now.